# why date pipe is showing wrong format in chrome,chromium and opera?

Tags: angular, datetime-format, date-pipe

[i have given date format as date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' but it is showing 02-03-2020 24:45:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyGIp.png)
Hi guys, we are using angular 4. we are using angular **date pipe** to format date as **dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss**. from last one week the format is not working properly instead of showing **02-03-2020 00:45:00** for early morning ,it is showing 02-03-2020 24:45:00 which is wrong.
Can anyone tell us why it is behaving like this .

**Note : in firefox it is showing correctly but showing wrongly in chrome,chromium,opera**

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade you application to a newer version of Angular. The Date Pipe problem was corrected in version 5:

Stackblitz to reproduce your error in Angular 4: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scxsq6

Same code but upgraded to Angular 5 works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cf3ajh

And more information about the problem: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8319#issuecomment-318576526